# postgresql equivalent to $mysqli->insert_id

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis, psql, postgresql-9.3

Is there an equivalent to  $mysqli->insert_id in postgresql 9.3? I am importing into one table, but I need to take the last primary key created in the table and apply it as a foreign key in the second table? Table 1 ----> Table 2 to complete a record.

A bit more info:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id,  eventdate) VALUES ('$_POST[site_id]','$_POST[eventdate]') returning id";
```

**Using the sql above, i insert my record, how would I then utilise this in my next SQL insert, If i use returning id, where is this ID stored, How do I use it on another INSERT statement?

```
 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO record_tbl (line, taxom_id, number_of_taxom, sheet_id) VALUES (1,1,'$_POST[cased_numbers]','$_POST[sheet_id]')";
  $result = pg_query($sql1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are need the PK of the row you just inserted (or any expression using the table's columns), you can use the RETURNING clause. Docs: [RETURNING clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

Eg.

```
test=# create table a (id serial, val text);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "a_id_seq" for serial column "a.id"
CREATE TABLE

test=# insert into a (val) values ('foo') returning id;
 id 
----
  1
```

Comment: However is this safe if multiple users are logged in at once?

Comment: If "logged in" = "performing multiple inserts", then the answer would be yes if you are returning an auto-generated primary key like a monotonically incrementing sequence. Either way, you cannot have duplicate primary keys, so if two users submitted the same PK, one of them is going to fail and the RETURNING clause is not going to return the PK of the failure.

Comment: I think the issue is that, two users logged in both create a sheet, so we have two sheet_ID's (PK) when they go to make a record, will your solution know which PK belongs to which user to that it is assigned as a FK in the correct record?

Comment: @Tom The `returning` clause returns the results of current query. So if user1 inserts a sheet with `id = 123` the query will return `123`. It doesnt matter, how many users perform the query at the same time.

Comment: The sheet_id is not a true primary key until it is successfully added to the table's PK column. Up to the point where that succeeds, the sheet_id's are just some values. So yes, because of the guaranteed uniqueness of the primary key, only one user's action is going to succeed, and returns the sheet_id that just got inserted. The second user will get an error, which will need to be trapped and handled. As Mark mentioned in his answer, using a sequence as DEFAULT is a way to guarantee the atomicity of the insert, without having to trap the resulting PK violation.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, the primary key values usually come from a sequence as a best practice. You can use `SELECT currval('sequence_name');` to get the last value of a particular sequence or `SELECT lastval()` to get the last value of any sequence. See the [official docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) for details.

You can see an example of `currval` working in this [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8f7db/1). Be aware that it is required use the sequence already in the session, as the insert would do. Calling `currval` when the sequence hasn't been used in the current session is an error.

If you are using PDO in PHP, the lastInsertId method there is supported by PostgreSQL, but requires you to provide the sequence ID. More [docs and discussion about PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) are available.

As @bma suggests, using a `RETURNING` clause on your `INSERT` statement is a good way to get back the value of the primary key of the row you just inserted:

```
insert into a (val) values ('foo') returning id;
```

Also, your syntax appears that it could be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack, because you are passing unvalidated input directly into the database without escaping it. Consider using [`pg_query_params`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) or some other alternative to make sure your inputs are properly escaped.

Comment: This is more of on the lines that I need, as it is safe for multiple users using the system. Though I am not fully sure how i would go about integrating it. I will add some extra information into my question.

Comment: `currval` is not safe - it will throw an error if the sequence was not used in current session.

Comment: I do plan on running it through drupal which should enable me to prevent users from injecting. However I will look at this more so once I have a working example.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: It is not universally safe, but it safe in this context. I updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy you can do it in one query:

```
WITH sheet AS(
    INSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id,  eventdate) VALUES ('$_POST[site_id]','$_POST[eventdate]') returning id
)
INSERT INTO record_tbl select 1,1,'$_POST[cased_numbers]',id FROM sheet;
```