# SELECT CURRVAL (pg_get_serial_sequence Im doing something wrong?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.3

What am I doing wrong, I am trying to get the last record_id from a table, after the first statement inserts it into my table. I seem to just print the code that is meant to display the last id?

```
      SELECT CURRVAL (pg_get_serial_sequence('sheet_tbl','sheet_id'))";
```

**Code here**

```
  else {
        echo 'Record added';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id,  eventdate, eventtime, username, additionalvolunteers) VALUES ('$_POST[site_id]','$_POST[eventdate]','$_POST[eventtime]', '$username','$_POST[additionalvolunteers]')";

        echo $sql; //Just so I can see what is getting sent
        $result = pg_query($sql);

        $sheet_id_pull = "SELECT CURRVAL (pg_get_serial_sequence('sheet_tbl','sheet_id'))";
        echo $sheet_id_pull; //This is where im having the issue with the above line.
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: When I use the above select curravl, when I echo the variable It is just printing the select currval statement. So I am obviously typing something wrong I think

Comment: That sounds more like a PHP(?) problem rather than a Postgres problem, because the statement itself is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
echo pg_query($sheet_id_pull);
```

Instead of

```
echo $sheet_id_pull;
```

Or

```
$sheet_id_pull = pg_query("SELECT CURRVAL (pg_get_serial_sequence('sheet_tbl','sheet_id'))");
echo $sheet_id_pull;
```

Also read [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860622/postgresql-equivalent-to-mysqli-insert-id) question. It has a better way of getting the inserted id.

Comment: It is at least not printing the statement, however it says Resource id #40 ?

Comment: I looked at the question from yesterday, however I had an issue with where to place the resource id, as it thinks it is a column.               $sql = "INSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id,  eventdate) VALUES ('$_POST[site_id]','$_POST[eventdate]')returning id";

Comment: @Tom You need something like `pg_fetch_row($sheet_id_pull)` to access the results of the query. Read [`this`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) manual for examples.

Comment: @Tom If you want to return the value, you inserted into `sheet_id` column - write `... returning sheet_id`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know sometimes its a basic question, but when its all new, These little questions help. Cheers